# Making Tr elements mobile compatible

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

I've been struggling with developing an email template as I've been attempting to make it mobile responsive. For the holiday listings at the top, I'm trying to have it 3 listings per row for desktop browsers however; for mobile browsers I want to only have it one listing per row to make it look appropriate for mobile devices.

The issue here is that `<tr>` does not support me making the `td` elements 100% width as the other elements are enclosed within the `<tr>` container` and I've been told email clients suggest tabular designs so I havent used divs as floats arent supported etc. P.S. Sorry for messy code, Apparently inline styles are most appropriate for emails. Here is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOPNXw

```
<div style="padding:20px; background-color:rgb(37,119,161);">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15037-4.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Eureka Spa</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 10-08-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Make our way into Daylesford for some great bargain hunting. &nbsp;No visit to Daylesford is complete without a visit to the Chocolate Mill for some home-made chocolates and a nice hot chocolate!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Eureka-Spa"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=122"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15043-4.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Mildura Music Festival </h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 24-09-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Grab your hat and board the country music express. The country music kicks in as soon as you step onto the coach, and you will be <br>pumping out the vibes as you cruise the open highway up to the riverside town of Mildura. You will be bootscootin, shakin' your bootie, line dancing and any other way you like to do your thing!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Mildura-Music-Festival   "><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=123"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15049-1.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Wangaratta Jazz &amp; Blues</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 29-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Travel to the Jazz Festival and embrace all the goodness that Wangaratta has to offer!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Wangaratta-Jazz-and-Blues"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=124"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15048-2.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">WA Dolphin Delights</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 24-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Get to visit the amazing beaches and far less populated West. Prepare for a great time seeing the Dolphins. Be carried away by the <br>beautiful sights of Perth from Kings Park!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/WA-Dolphin-Delights"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=130"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15040-1.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Camels, Pearls &amp; Whales</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 03-09-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Discover the Dinosaurs footprints at low tide, have an exciting&nbsp;camel ride along Cable Beach, and enjoy how&nbsp;rich the wildlife&nbsp;is at the spectacular Broome!&nbsp;</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Camels-Pearls-and-Whales"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=131"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15046-3.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Sunset Markets</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 17-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Make your way to Berry Springs to the Territory Wildlife Park where you&nbsp;can view the wildlife up close, take a walk around the lagoon, go into the walk-through aquarium to view the amazing aquatic life and come nose to nose with a giant saltwater crocodile! This afternoon we are off to Berry Springs Nature Park for a refreshing swim. Don’t forget to wear your goggles so you can see many small native fish and other aquatic life that live in the clear pools. Wildlife is abundant!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Sunset-Markets"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=135"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you use a display: block? I'm don't know, is it posible to use it on email markup

Comment: A table and `display:block` for tr and td would indeed have been the solution for normal websites. If you could have used @media queries. With e-mail clients however, all bets are off. A quick and dirty test shows that the @media trick works in SeaMonkey (and presumably Thunderbird), but not on the gmail website. So I wouldn't get your hopes up. But does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16200231/1016716) help?

Comment: Didnt really work with my code, the td element moved out of the table element for some reason even though I coded the table within the td. Anyway, I guess i'll have to do a bounty on this one. Thanks anyway mate

Comment: just add `display: inline-block;` for parent div element. it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use TH instead of TD.  TD in android no longer works for responsive design. See http://labs.actionrocket.co/ for more info on this.

TH has some quirks (defaults to text-align:center and font-weight:bold) and padding can be a bit weird, but it will still allow for you to use the block stack method in a single table instead of stacking tables.

There are a couple things on this though.

1.) Gmail App and those mobile clients that do not read media queries will still display at 3 column when using below code. To solve this, you would need to create this as first the mobile version (use the media query in your current as the inline and then set media queries, conditional code and max-widths, etc in style sheet to display correctly on desktop.) which is easier said than done, and will require much testing using a tool such as Email on Acid or Litmus.

2.) Some of the divs and button tags are not cross client compatable. See here for CSS compatability in HTML email: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and here for creating cross-client buttons: http://buttons.cm/.

See below for your code using the TH stack method:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px), screen and (max-width: 600px) {
th[class=colsplit]{width:100%!important; float:left!important; display:block !important;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%">
<div style="padding:20px; background-color:rgb(37,119,161);">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15037-4.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Eureka Spa</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 10-08-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Make our way into Daylesford for some great bargain hunting. &nbsp;No visit to Daylesford is complete without a visit to the Chocolate Mill for some home-made chocolates and a nice hot chocolate!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Eureka-Spa"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=122"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>

    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15043-4.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Mildura Music Festival </h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 24-09-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Grab your hat and board the country music express. The country music kicks in as soon as you step onto the coach, and you will be <br>pumping out the vibes as you cruise the open highway up to the riverside town of Mildura. You will be bootscootin, shakin' your bootie, line dancing and any other way you like to do your thing!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Mildura-Music-Festival   "><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=123"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>

    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15049-1.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Wangaratta Jazz &amp; Blues</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 29-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Travel to the Jazz Festival and embrace all the goodness that Wangaratta has to offer!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Wangaratta-Jazz-and-Blues"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=124"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>
</tr><tr>
    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15048-2.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">WA Dolphin Delights</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 24-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Get to visit the amazing beaches and far less populated West. Prepare for a great time seeing the Dolphins. Be carried away by the <br>beautiful sights of Perth from Kings Park!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/WA-Dolphin-Delights"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=130"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>

    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15040-1.JPG_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Camels, Pearls &amp; Whales</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 03-09-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Discover the Dinosaurs footprints at low tide, have an exciting&nbsp;camel ride along Cable Beach, and enjoy how&nbsp;rich the wildlife&nbsp;is at the spectacular Broome!&nbsp;</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Camels-Pearls-and-Whales"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=131"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>

    <th class="colsplit" style="width:30%; margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">
        <img src="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/panel/upload/thumbnails/0CM15046-3.jpg_listing" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; padding: 5px; color:orange; font-weight:bold;">Sunset Markets</h3>
        <h3 style="padding: 5px; color:orange;">Departing on: 17-10-2015</h3>
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; padding:20px; background-color:white;"><p>Make your way to Berry Springs to the Territory Wildlife Park where you&nbsp;can view the wildlife up close, take a walk around the lagoon, go into the walk-through aquarium to view the amazing aquatic life and come nose to nose with a giant saltwater crocodile! This afternoon we are off to Berry Springs Nature Park for a refreshing swim. Don’t forget to wear your goggles so you can see many small native fish and other aquatic life that live in the clear pools. Wildlife is abundant!</p></div>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/holiday/Sunset-Markets"><button style=" display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">View</button></a>
        <a href="http://au.clubmatestravel.com/contact?mode=enquiry&amp;tour=135"><button style="  display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-image: none;border: 1px solid transparent;white-space: nowrap;padding: 6px 12px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;width:100%; float:left;height:50px; color: #fff; background-color: #47a447; border-color: #398439; ">Enquire</button></a>
    </th>
</tr><tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Such a peculiar solution, but worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of table rows with each td set to 30%, using nested tables can help achieve consistent display in different email readers, and to stop them stacking at wider viewports, set float:left; (or display:inline-block).

Then use media queries to set the width of your nested tables to 100% as required. Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/pJYryK

Typical code is:

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>           
</head>  
...
<table class="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="nested"><tr><td>table 1</td></tr></table>
      <table class="nested"><tr><td>table 2</td></tr></table>
      <table class="nested"><tr><td>table 3</td></tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.nested{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  table.nested{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: using float in HTML emails is not recommended. Your answer is correct, but leaves vulnerability to some of the more restrictive email clients, such as Outlook. With adding align instead of float, and defining a value on desktop (or using MSO conditional) you can probably use this method, but would also need to take into account the extra 'padding' Outlook adds in-between tables.

Comment: @Gortonington , yes I agree that my suggestion would take some refiniing to get consistent results across some email clients